# AST node attributes vs subtrees

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, language-design

In an AST, what should be the attributes of a node and what should be subtrees of a node? For example, if a variable declaration has a type, should that type be expressed in a subtree or as an attribute of an identifier node?

Answer (score 0):

The Abstract **Syntax** Tree follows the *syntax* of the construct it is modelling. The syntax of a variable *declaration* normally consists of an *identifier* and a *type* (as well as some punctuation, which might not find it's way into the AST), and those will be child nodes of the *declaration* node.

Normally, the attribute of the identifier node will be a link to a symbol table entry, which will eventually refer in some way to the declared type of the identifier. But semantic analysis is not really part of the parse; in most cases, it will be done in a subsequent walk of the AST.